# Updating a Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this

```
$array =
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product] =>  Amazing Widget
            [Value] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Super Amazing Widget
            [Value] => 400
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Product] =>  Promising Widget 
            [Value] => 300
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Superb Widget
            [Value] => 400
        )
    }
```

I want to update the array to change "Promising Widget" to 800 instead of 300.

Note that the order of this array is arbitrary, meaning that I need to update the Value Based on the "Product" name value (not on it's number in the array).

I was trying to access it via the number in the array but realized that wouldn't work for that reason and I'm not sure how to change the value of one element of a multidimensional array based on another.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try this..loop through and search for the desired product and save its key.then change the value associated with that key?

Comment: are you generating this array, can you change the structure?

Comment: As @Alex noted, it might be better to use a hash with the key being the Product Name.  Each entry would be a hash of properties.

Answer (score 29):

```
foreach($array as &$value){
    if($value['Product'] === 'Promising Widget'){
        $value['Value'] = 800;
        break; // Stop the loop after we've found the item
    }
}
```

So, you loop through the array, find value you want, then change it.  The `&$value` is so the array is passed by reference.  Meaning we can directly edit the values in the array from the loop, without having to do `$array[$key]['Value']`.

Comment: You should add `unset($value);` at the end, see the first big red **Warning** in [foreach, the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: In a key value array, you can do this as well. 
                        foreach($array as $key=> &$values){
    $values['value'] = $new_value;
   }

Answer (score 13):

I think you'd have to loop through them, something like:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  if ($v['Product']=='Promising Widget') {
    $array[$k]['Value']=800;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think that most universal approach is to use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function like that:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, 'updateValue');

function updateValue(&$data, $key) {
  if($key == 'Promising Widget') {
    $data = 800;
  }
}
```

This way even if you will change your array later on this function still will be working fine.

Comment: surely not the 'most universal approach'. From the manual page: `Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function. `

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be too late, but I faced a similar issues which I solved using this function

```
function r_search_and_replace( &$arr ) {
    foreach ( $arr as $idx => $_ ) {
        if( is_array( $_ ) ) r_search_and_replace( $arr[$idx] );
        else {
            if( is_string( $_ ) ) $arr[$idx] = str_replace( "PATTERN", "REPLACEMENT", $_ );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who expect for a most complicated array, use a recursive function to go through all the elements

(assume this function is in a php class, then)

```
public function reGenerateArray(&$arr)
{
    array_walk($arr, function (&$v, $k ) {
        if($k === 'KEY_NAME') {
            $v['OTHER_KEY'] = $newValueToReplace;
        } elseif("array" == gettype($v)) {
            $this->reGenerateArray($v);
        }
    });
}
```

*This function will reproduce the existing array*