# how to update the value of json data label with the new value using php?

Tags: php, json

I want to update the label value using PHP. Suppose if I enter the same label then it'll match if there exists any same label named, then it'll update the value of that label.

```
[{
    "label": "aa",
    "val": "12"
},
{
    "label": "new",
    "val": "13"
},
{
    "label": "yy",
    "val": "14"
}]
```

in that above data.json i want to update the value of label : "yy" to val: "20". For this I'm using this code

```
$myFile = "data.json";
$arr_data = array(); // create empty array
try
{
    //Get form data
    $formdata = array(
        'label'=> $_POST['label'],
        'val' => $_POST['val']
    );
    //Get data from existing json file
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);
    // converts json data into array
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    foreach($arr_data as $item){
    }
    // array_push($arr_data,$formdata);
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    /*this is the matching label code*/
    if(in_array($formdata['label'],$item)){
        $item['val'] = $formdata['val'];
        echo $item['val'];
        echo "got it";
    }
    else echo "not matched";
    //write json data into data.json file
    if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {       
    }
    else 
        echo "error";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: You need to indent your code properly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179961/updating-a-multidimensional-array-in-php   This will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code to match label name inside `foreach` loop so that each label value in json array can be compared. Updated Code:

```
$myFile = "data.json";
try {
//Get form data
    $formdata = array(
        'label' => $_POST['label'],
        'val' => $_POST['val']
    );
    //Get data from existing json file
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);
   // converts json data into array
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    foreach ($arr_data as $key => $item) {
        /* this is the matching label code */
        if ($formdata['label'] == $item["label"]) {
            $arr_data[$key]["val"] = $formdata['val'];
            echo $item['val'];
            echo "got it";
        } else
            echo "not matched";
    }
  //write json data into data.json file
    if (!file_put_contents($myFile, json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))) {
        echo "error";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace.
The pattern of a Json is very predictable.
Using regex means you don't need to decode and encode or even iterate the array.

```
$label = "yy";
$val = 20;

echo preg_replace("/label\":\s*\"" . $label . "\",\s*\"val\":\s*\"\d+/",
                  "label\": \"" . $label . "\", \"val\": \"". $val, 
                  $json);
```

https://3v4l.org/m4rDa

---

If you need to know if the label has been updated then you can use this:

```
$label = "yy";
$val = 20;

$new = Preg_replace("/label\":\s*\"" . $label . "\",\s*\"val\":\s*\"\d+/",
                  "label\": \"" . $label . "\", \"val\": \"". $val, 
                  $json);
If($json != $new){
    Echo "label updated\n";
}else{
    Echo "nothing found\n";
}
Echo $new;
```

It will compare the "old" Json with the new and if they don't match the lable has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative solution with json_decode() and json_encode()

```
$jsonData = '[
    {
        "label": "aa",
        "val": "12"
    },
    {
        "label": "new",
        "val": "13"
    },
    {
        "label": "yy",
        "val": "14"
    }
]';

echo '<strong>Before update</strong>';
echo '<pre>';
echo $jsonData;
echo '</pre>';

$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);


foreach ($jsonArray as $key => $jsonRow) {
    if (isset($jsonRow['label']) && $jsonRow['label'] == 'yy') {
        $jsonArray[$key]['val'] = 20;
    }
}

$jsonData = json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo '<strong>After update</strong>';
echo '<pre>';
echo $jsonData;
echo '</pre>';
```

This code will give output

**Before update**

```
[
    {
        "label": "aa",
        "val": "12"
    },
    {
        "label": "new",
        "val": "13"
    },
    {
        "label": "yy",
        "val": "14"
    }
]
```

**After update**

```
[
    {
        "label": "aa",
        "val": "12"
    },
    {
        "label": "new",
        "val": "13"
    },
    {
        "label": "yy",
        "val": 20
    }
]
```